# spring boot start from bat or cmd file

Tags: java, windows, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

How do I run a Spring boot jar application from bat or cmd file? When start the executable jar in the command line everything works, but when I run it as a bat file, Spring return 404 code from a request.

Log from console

```
2016-01-15 14:06:52.408 DEBUG 5104 --- [http-nio-81-exec-10] o.s.b.c.web.OrderedRequestContextFilter  : Bound request context to thread: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@1899d750

2016-01-15 14:06:52.417 DEBUG 5104 --- [http-nio-81-exec-10] o.s.b.c.web.OrderedRequestContextFilter  : Cleared thread-bound request context: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@1899d750
```

In browser after spring security redirect to login page I have 404.

Comment: Please take a [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: How do you start it from a bat file? Please add it :)

Comment: Command in bat file: java -jar b2b-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar --debug

Comment: How do you build your jar? Do you have spring-boot maven plugin in your pom.xml if you are building it with maven?

Comment: yes i have maven and i building it with maven

Answer (score 1):

1. Open notepad or any other text editor
2. Copy & paste the below code

   ```
   call mvn clean install

   call mvn spring-boot:run
   ```
3. Save as fileName.bat or fileName.cmd

Answer (score 0):

Just place your bat file in the same directory where your jar has been generated. Because currently it is searching for jar file in your current directory where your bat file is located.

Answer (score 0):

Run with Maven using `mvn spring-boot:run -Drun.arguments=--debug`

The plugin will build and run in one step.

Comment: The 404 might be happening because the `.bat` file is being executed from a different directory than what is being expected.